# Display the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, & 5th date of the current week in php

Tags: php, html, date, dayofweek

Ok, So im trying to figure out the best way in php to write (or print) the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, & 5th date of the current week (starting with Monday) in php.

For example... Using the week of the 4th through the 8th of February...

I would need a script for the 1st day of the week (starting with Monday) displayed as **February 04, 2013** and then I would need the same script **four more times** to display Tues, Wed, Thurs, & Fri...

All-together I would end up with **5 scripts** or one script that I could copy and manipulate to work the way I need it to...

Also, If you could tell me how to do the same for Saturday and Sunday that would be greatly appreciated as-well.

If there is anything that you do not understand, please let me know and I will try my hardest to clarify...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the "current" week's Monday. To do this, I would suggest calling `date("N")` and see if it's 1. If it is, then `now` is the Monday you want. Otherwise `last monday` is. Pass that to `strtotime` to get the timestamp corresponding to the first monday of the week. Then repeatedly add 24 hours (24*3600 seconds) to get each day.

```
$startofweek = date("N") == 1 ? time() : strtotime("last monday");
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $day = $startofweek + 24*3600*$i;
    echo "Day ".($i+1).": ".date("d/M/Y",$day)."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Why those checks when there is a simpler solution, monday this week?

Comment: @JStormThaKid Exactly what the error says. Add `date_default_timezone_set` at the beginning of your code, or define one properly in the configuration.

Comment: @Kolink - I just want to say THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! I was able to tweak your code to exactly what I needed. This is exactly what I was looking for... Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime with special parameters. like:

```
$time = strtotime('monday this week');
$time = strtotime('today');
$time = strtotime('next monday');
$time = strtotime('previous monday');
```

Same goes for every other days of the week